# didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation iOS5 replacement

Tags: ios5, deprecated

`didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS 5.0.  However I would like to use this method in my application. I am using the sample code that Apple offers in the iOS Dev Center, project name `AlternateViews`. I would like the app to rotate the `portraitView` while fading in the `landscapeView`. Can this be done in iOS 5 or is this feature forever gone?

`portraitView` currently calls:

`[self presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController animated:YES];`

while `landscapeView` calls this in code in the `init` method:

`self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`

It appears all of the animation is done in the following PortraitViewController.m:

```
#import "PortraitViewController.h"
#import "LandscapeViewController.h"

@implementation PortraitViewController

@synthesize landscapeViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:197.0/255.0 green:204.0/255.0 blue:211.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    LandscapeViewController *viewController = [[LandscapeViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithNibName:@"LandscapeView" bundle:nil];
    self.landscapeViewController = viewController;
    [viewController release];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.landscapeViewController = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] endGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    [landscapeViewController release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // We must add a delay here, otherwise we'll swap in the new view
    // too quickly and we'll get an animation glitch
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}

- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController animated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }    
}

// override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); // support only portrait
}

@end
```

Here is my current implementation files which fail miserably.
PortraitViewController.m:

```
#import "PortraitViewController.h"
#import "LandscapeViewController.h"

@implementation PortraitViewController

@synthesize landscapeViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    LandscapeViewController *viewController = [[LandscapeViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithNibName:@"LandscapeView" bundle:nil];
    self.landscapeViewController = viewController;
    [viewController release];
    NSLog(@"Portrait viewDidLoad");
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.landscapeViewController = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{   
    [landscapeViewController release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation Portrait");
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Portrait-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation Landscape");
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

}

- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait-present Landscape");
        [self presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController animated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        NSLog(@"Portrait-dismiss Landscape");
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }    
}

// override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}

@end
```

LandscapeViewController.m

```
#import "LandscapeViewController.h"

@implementation LandscapeViewController

// the designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; // we want to overlap the status bar.

        // when presented, we want to display using a cross dissolve
        self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    oldStatusBarStyle = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarStyle];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"Landscape viewWillAppear");
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:oldStatusBarStyle animated:NO];    
}

// override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // return YES for supported orientations
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
    //return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation Portrait");
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        NSLog(@"Landscape-willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation Landscape");

    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apple's [UIViewController reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you'll find this useful paragraph in the "Handling View Rotations" section:

> If you want to perform custom animations during an orientation change,
>   you can do so in one of two ways. Orientation changes used to occur in
>   two steps, with notifications occurring at the beginning, middle, and
>   end points of the rotation. However, in iOS 3.0, support was added for
>   performing orientation changes in one step. Using a one-step
>   orientation change tends to be faster than the older two-step process
>   and is generally recommended for any new code.
>
> To add animations for an orientation change, override the
>   [willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation%3aduration%3a) method and perform
>   your animations there.

Could you override the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:` method to do your animations?

Comment: I believe that would work, however I'm a novice programmer so I might need a little more assistance.  I am thinking that you would have the PortraitView accept all rotations so that it would rotate to landscape and then use `willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration` to `presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController`. Is this correct logic or would I use `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` and inside this method tell the PortraitView to rotate and then `presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController`?

Comment: If the code you've edited your question to add above works well, why not call your `updateLandscapeView` method from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` (and with a delay, even). I wouldn't use any of the `*HalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation` methods at all, as they are deprecated and could possibly disappear in iOS 6 or iOS 7. In any event, the feature you were looking for is not "forever" gone... it's just been changed to be somewhat more future-proof.  You should be able to modify your working code to take advantage of the new API's.

Comment: I went with your suggestion and called the `updateLandscapeView` method from `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation`.  However I also had to add code to the LandscapeView to have it disappear as I only longer could rely on notifications.  I thought I had it working well when I ran the application and found I only made things worse.  The landscapeView doesn't fade on but appears to slide diagonally on and the views are sometimes shown when they shouldn't be.  Could you help me out some more on this? (posted code above) Thanks so much.