# iOS 6 Rotation: Pushing a View Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, ios6

I want to support iOS 6 rotation. Trouble is, I've been looking through a lot of documentation and stack overflow questions but have not found any even slightly in depth solutions. I've only seen that I should add these two methods to my view controller classes - however, if I'm not mistaken, they do not operate in the same way as the pre iOS 6 methods:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll; // use what is appropriate for you.
}
```

My app currently rotates in pre-iOS6 using the following code. Note that I use the interface orientation parameters to determine whether or not I'm going to push my view Controller. How do I implement this in the iOS 6 rotation delegates?

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    UIInterfaceOrientation toOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;

    if ( self.tabBarController.view.subviews.count >= 2 )
    {
        UIView *tabBar = [self.tabBarController.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1];

        if(toOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft && toOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            CUSTOM_DEBUG_LOG("\n\nRotated back to Portrait");
            tabBar.hidden = FALSE;
        }
    }
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        CUSTOM_DEBUG_LOG("\nView going landscape");
        ScrollViewController *s = [[ScrollViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ScrollViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:s animated:NO];
        [s release];
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    }

}
```

Comment: Watch the WWDC 2012 movie about view controllers.

Comment: I think I did not properly phrase my question, because my app is working without any of the answers here. I basically wasn't able to get rotation working in iOS and I thought that the willAnimate... functions were deprecated as well. Turns out, they aren't. So my app still works. Hooray? 

Unfortunately, I have gigantic unsightly white bars on my page which I need to get rid of. Time to post another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697473/didanimatefirsthalfofrotationtointerfaceorientation-ios5-replacement) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595471/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-popviewcontrolleranimate) SO discussion.

[EDIT]

Yes the methods you mentioned aren't deprecated in iOS 6.0 and they will continue working. It's just the way Auto Rotation works have been changed. So far it was view controllers responsibility to decide whether they rotate or not but now RootViewController will decide whether their children should rotate or not. If you don't have rootviewcontroller setup then you have to add it to window and then put shouldAutoRotate and supportedInterfaceOrientations methods in the rootviewcontroller.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that looks like it's just moving the code out of my willAnimate Function into another function, which looks nicer but functionally does nothing more.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. Edited my answer.

Comment: what is `updateLayoutForNewOrientation`? it's not an official function called by the framework ... did you copy that from someone else answer but forget the part where it is called ?

Comment: @Bastian sorry I forgot to remove it. It is user defined function defined willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation delegate -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595471/willanimaterotationtointerfaceorientation-not-called-on-popviewcontrolleranimate

Answer (score 3):

Parent Views now handle rotation in iOS 6.  Subclass your nav controllers and add a bool

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;  // your rotation here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand. Could you give me a snippet of sample code or show me how I would deal with pushing my view controllers? You literally just pasted back the first block of code (with a slightly different return) to me and that doesn't help me at all.

I should mention that the reason I'm pushing a separate view controller for landscape mode is because the landscape UI is completely different from the portrait.

Comment: You might want to consider rewriting that code so that you simply change the layout on a rotation.  If the different UI has the same components that would be straightforward.  If there are different components, then you can show/hide appropriately.  If you really want to keep separate view controllers, then it would probably work best if there was a parent view controller that added/removed and/or show/hid the appropriate child view controller on a rotation... that way you don't have to deal with the behind the scenes functionality of pushing/popping view controllers on a rotation.

Comment: Is pushing/popping inefficient or something highly undesirable? The app is highly similar to the iPhone's music app where if you tilt sideways on any of the tabbar's view controllers(yes, my app has a tabbar), you get thrown into coverflow. For my app, you get thrown into a my landscape viewcontroller. It appears to work well for iOS 5 and below but I'm trying to figure things out for iOS 6. I also _must_ maintain compatibility with older versions of iOS.

Comment: Override your rotation by subclassing your navigation controller pushing to your landscape view to maintain backwards compatibility.  Eg.  set the global rotation for your app as portrait in summary tab of xcode.  Then override that in your subclass for your parent view view controller to your landscape view controller  allowing landscape

Comment: Sorry, I'm still quite new to Objective C. Does subclassing mean to create another class which inherits from my navigation controller? 

Regardless, I think I found my own problem. I may not have implemented the iOS6 rotation code correctly when I first posted the question.

I incorrectly thought that the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation function was deprecated in iOS6, leading me to believe that there was a new iOS rotation delegate with an orientation parameter. Turns out this is not the case, so my app sort of works.

Comment: It has white bars everywhere...so I'm going to have to make a new SO topic for that.

Is it standard practise for me to give you the tick for the answer if you provided the most help, even if your answer did not solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I may not have implemented the iOS6 rotation code correctly when I first posted the question.

I incorrectly thought that the willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation function was deprecated in iOS6, leading me to believe that there was a new iOS rotation delegate with an orientation parameter. Turns out this is not the case, so my app sort of works.

The code I plugged into my app was just this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);
}
```

Comment: +1 for "copy and paste"-ability.  Didn't feel like looking up orientation mask merging syntax...

Comment: The convenience value UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown is even more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a UINavigationController, override `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods = YES` property.

Then like Mark S said, also override `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` for the children VCs.

Comment: Nice! Good catch. I'll give you an upboat (: